# I want to implement islamic calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, hijri

I am developing an in flutter and I need to implement an Islamic Calendar in the app. There is no proper resources available on the google does anyone know how to implement it.

Comment: Will this help: https://pub.dev/packages/hijri

Comment: I am a beginner can you provide some code

Comment: The package itself has some examples on how to use it. If it is not enough; I'm afraid you'll have to learn more about Flutter. Stack Overflow can help you work out specific issues, but we can't write your code for you.

Comment: I am actually working on it. Let me know if you implement it before me.

Answer (score 1):

after a quick google search, check out [this flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/hijri)

Comment: I am a beginner can you provide some code